# JPQL create Query Throws parsing exception

Tags: java, jpql, java-ee-6

The following query fails when I use createQuery

```
select MAX(kcc.order) From KPIConfiguration kcc join EnumerationValue ev on kcc.level = ev.enumerationValueId join EnumerationValue ev1 on kcc.dataSource = ev1.enumerationValueId where ev1.key = :dataSource
```

with the following exception

> Exception: "Encountered "join EnumerationValue ev" at character 49,
> but expected: [".", "FETCH", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", ]."
> while parsing JPQL "select MAX(kcc.order) From KPIConfiguration kcc
> join EnumerationValue ev on kcc.level = ev.enumerationValueId join
> EnumerationValue ev1 on kcc.dataSource = ev1.enumerationValueId where
> ev1.key = :dataSource"

but when I use createNativeQuery as follows, it works.

```
select MAX(kcc.ORDERS) From KPI_CHECKLIST_CONF kcc join ENUMERATION_VALUE ev on kcc.LEVELS = ev.ENUMERATION_VALUE_ID join ENUMERATION_VALUE ev1 on kcc.DATA_SOURCE = ev1.ENUMERATION_VALUE_ID where ev1.ENUMERATION_KEY = ?1
```

I couldn't understand the reason. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the levels field in your KPIConfiguration entity? if it's an entity relationship ie. it's an instance of the EnumerationValue entity, then you don't need the on and you can just use `join kcc.level ev`.

Comment: levels not mapped.  @Column(name = "LEVELS")
    private Long level; it's a key of ENUMERATION_VALUE  used in KPI_CHECKLIST_CONF